# Codeigniter - On clean install redirect() isn't working

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I have done a clean codeigniter(v2.2.6) installation, configured and welcome page working. I have added `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');` on autoload. Welcome page etc. all working. Using WAMP.

My problem is any `redirect()` is giving me an error with message:
This page isn’t working
localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

This is my very simple form referring to crypt controller.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="crypt/process_encrypt" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="message">
  <input type="submit" value="encrypt message">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Crypt extends CI_Controller {


  public function process_encrypt()
  {
    redirect('/welcome/index');
  }
}
```

EDIT: USING V3 NOW, PROBLEM IS CONSISTENT.

Comment: is this behavior consistent across browsers?

Comment: @coderodour I'm using chrome, but i will check out IE.

Comment: @coderodour consistent.

Comment: CI 2 was discontinued exactly **2 years ago**. This isn't a legacy project; you have no excuse for using obsolete software.

Comment: @narf I had more errors on v3, it's for an assignment which are based on v2 and i have 1 week to learn codeigniter, stressing majorly :P.

Comment: check your http request, where is it actually attempting to redirect to?

Comment: @Kisaragi how do you do that?

Comment: @Hyrule can you please check base_url in config file?

Comment: @usmanikram $config['base_url'] = '';

Comment: `$config['base_url'] ` MUST be set. For example `$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';`

Comment: @Hyrule please set base_url to the url of you code. e.g http://localhost/example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you configured the base_url in config file? 
*you have to set **base_url** in config file*

```
redirect('welcome/index');
```

> `redirect()` The function will build the URL based on your config file
>   values.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
redirect('/welcome/index');
```

to

```
redirect('welcome/index');
```